# Showing content of a PDF in an iFrame (path to file)

Tags: html, moqui

I have a stored PDF and I want to display it in an iFrame. What is the appropriate way to calculate the src?

I used this but that did not work for me:

```
<set field="resourceReference" from="ec.resource.getLocationReference('dbresource://mantle/content/cv/100000/content_100006/161107_HS.pdf')"/>
```

Then, in the HTML I added:

```
src="${resourceReference.getUrl()}"
```

Without success.

[image: field setup]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL from a ResourceReference is an internal URL (starting with dbresource:// in your example) and not a valid URL for a web client. You'll need to add a screen transition or something that streams the file to a web client (using something like the ec.web.sendResourceResponse(String location) method). There are various examples of transitions using this method in the framework, SimpleScreens, etc.

Comment: I added a transition with ec.web.sendResourceResponse('dbresource://mantle/content/cv/XYZ.pdf', true) with inline = true. Then I added an iframe with src src="${sri.buildUrl('getActualCV').url}".